# Avoid blocking in cliet side chat using msvcrt module

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, select, msvcrt

### The answer: use the class IOLoop of tornado module and errno module.

In addition, this is a good article about the subject: [Async I/O and Python](https://blogs.gnome.org/markmc/2013/06/04/async-io-and-python/)

---

I try to write a public chat when the client can write without waiting for server's replay. I want to print server's messages any time during the ability of the client to send messages any time (when he ENTER the message he typed send).

I know it can be done by threads but I also know that it can be done with msvcrt module.

This is the client side chat I got for now:

```
def list2string(my_msg):
    s = ""
    for item in my_msg:
        s += item
    return s

import socket, sys, select, msvcrt

my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1733))

socket_messages = [my_socket]
my_msg = []

try:
    while 1:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(socket_messages, socket_messages, [])
        for sock in rlist:
            if sock is my_socket:
                msg = my_socket.recv(1024)
                print msg

        if msvcrt.kbhit():                # if the client typed character
            char = msvcrt.getch()         # get this character
            if chr(13) is char:           # if enter
                my_string_msg = list2string(my_msg)
                print '[Me]', my_string_msg
                my_socket.send(my_string_msg)
                my_msg = [] 

            elif ord(char) == 8:     #backspace
                my_msg.pop()

            else:
                # else just show the character in the line
                # sys.stdout.write(char) --> this command?
                # but then if the server would message it will be mixed with it.
                my_msg.append(char)
finally:
    my_socket.close()
```

As you see, the main problem is how to write the letters that the client types during the printed messages that the server sends.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer: use the class IOLoop of tornado module and errno module.**

In addition, this is a good article about the subject: [Async I/O and Python](https://blogs.gnome.org/markmc/2013/06/04/async-io-and-python/)